# ANN algorithms for optimal path searching

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, neural-network

all. These days I've met a question on data analysis. I want to search an optimal path on a 3D landscape-like graph from a user-defined starting point to an end point. I've achieved it using rainfall algorithm and flood-fill algorithm before. Recently, I've heard about some aspect of machine-learning and artificial neural network and their ability in data analysis, so I want to know if there are some algorithms can be used for solving this problem.
Here is the description of my question: I have a 2D plain, say x-y plain. On the x axis, there are `m` points averagely distributed from `0` to `m_max`. For the same, there are `n` points averagely distributed from `0` to `n_max` on y axis. So there are `m*n` points on the plain and each point has different value `E_mn`. Then I have 3D landscape. For the definition of optimal path is that on this path from a starting point to the end point the maximum value is lowest among all the other paths and the length of the optimal path should be the shortest(shortest means minimum points it passed. If shortest can not be achieve easily, it's OK for only lowest.)

Comment: Why would you prefer training and predicting with a neural network over using a search algorithm?

Comment: @jorgenkg I heard about ANN in many articles, and was attracted by its ability in data analysis. I don't know to much about search algorithm cause I'm not a programmer. Maybe I can try what you suggest, but what kind of search algorithm is suitable for this problem? And does any ANN algorithm suit for this problem?

Comment: And also I heard of that ANN can solve problem like a human do. For a 3D landscape, man can directly point out which path has the lowest maximum and has min-length. So maybe ANN can do the same thing easily.

Comment: As @jorgenkg suggested - you xhould just do a simple path searching (A* for example). Do not use NN because "you heard something about them" - this is not how one should solve the problem. Yours is pretty simple, and best addressed by existing path searching methods (like A* and its modifications).

Comment: @lejlot what does A* mean? I 'm a little confused.

Comment: @zmwang it sounds like you should start off by reading some theory. Try [this introductory article on A*](http://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/a-star/introduction.html). A* is a search algorithm for finding the optimal path between two points.